# How to run browser instances in parallel with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to run two browser instances executing tests in parallel?

Sample code

```
# Test 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://translate.google.com/?sl=pt&tl=en&op=translate')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/div/input').send_keys('teste')

# Test 2
driver.get('https://translate.google.com/?sl=pt&tl=en&op=translate')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/div/input').send_keys('teste2')
```

Comment: try `driver_2 = webdriver.Chrome()` and use that driver for task 2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this through a unit testing framework like [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html).
Pytest has a plugin called [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/) supporting tests in parallel.

1. Install pytest and pytest-dist
2. Group the tests into test methods
3. Run the tests in parallel